# Python How do I fix my error on sock connect issue

Tags: python-3.x

How do I fix my error on sock.connect((???)).

Everything else seems to be in order, but I am getting a compile error. This is not so I can crack anything, I am just testing. I am a student and I am learning, this is not homework.

[image: ftp crack]

Comment: the IP is a random number for filler.

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to Stack Overflow! A few tips for your question; Whether or not it's homework doesn't matter, as long as a question is well-asked, it is acceptable. Some things that make a question well asked are a thorough explanation of the code, including what it is supposed to do, and what lines are throwing the compilation error, and what line(s) isn't doing what you expect. Also, don't ever include images of code. Instead, include the code in the question so that someone who wants to help you can copy the code into their own environment and run it to help find the errors.

Comment: Please reformat your question properly and do not paste screenshots of your code.

Comment: I have had issues using this site to post code.I found it easier to do screen shots.